# re - выделить число из строки

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения, qregularexpression

Я написал небольшой код. Моя цель — вывести пользователя, когда он введет число, например 5,5 или 5,5, вывести Y на консоль. Теперь, если пользователь вводит число, например 123.3 у меня работает код. Но при вводе числа типа 123,3 выдает ошибку. Можно ли это исправить?

```
import re
pattern = '\d{1,7}\.\d'
user = input()
if (re.search(pattern, user)):
    a = float(user)
    print(a, type(a))
    print("Y")
else:
    print("N")
```

Comment: потому что в `re.search` сначала передается "что искать", а потом - "где искать". Иными словами, должно быть `re.search(pattern. user)`.

Comment: Если юзер введёт `123` или `123.` - с таким паттерном пойдёт нафиг...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поправьте регулярное выражение так, чтобы оно пропускало числа с запятой в качестве символа десятичной дроби, а также захватите цифры до и после него в отдельные подмаски, а затем используйте эти два значения для парсинга числа:

```py
import re
pattern = r'^(\d{1,7})[.,](\d)$'
user = '123,3'
m = re.search(pattern, user)
if m:
    a = float(f'{m.group(1)}.{m.group(2)}')
    print(a, type(a))
    print("Y")
else:
    print("N")
```

См. [пример работы кода](https://ideone.com/Mlug02).

- `^` - начало строки
- `(\d{1,7})` - захватывающая подмаска №1 (`m.group(1)`): от одной до семи цифр
- `[.,]` - точка или запятая
- `(\d)` - захватывающая подмаска №2 (`m.group(2)`): одна цифра
- `$` - конец строки.

Comment: Спасибо огромное!